# Binding Repeater with entity framework and Jquery/Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

**I want to bind repeater with entity framework, that call a procedure in database(Speed purposes), i create an ajax web method to be called from jquery code to sent parameters. so it will decide what data to display.**

> Below is the ajax call that will sent the parameter to **showResult** web method, i use the ajax code to handle all data within one page, because i have drop down lists to handle user selections(every selection reflect a query in database).

```
            $.ajax({
                url: "WebService.asmx/showResult",
                type: "post",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    "dateFrom": $('#txtDateFrom').val(),
                    "dateTo": $('#txtDateTo').val(),
                    "ddlType": $("#ddlType").children("option").filter(":selected").val(),
                    "ddlTer": $("#ddlTer").children("option").filter(":selected").val()
                }), // parameters
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#loader').html('<img src="Images/loading.gif" />');
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#loader').html('');
                    //To delete the whole tr except the first one.
                    $("#tblUsers").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                    $('#tblUsers').append(JSON.stringify(result));
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
```

also, below is the web method **showResult** code that will call the proc with parameters:

```
  public string showResult(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo)
  {

      string result = "  ";
 var sp = db.select_alltypes(dateFrom, dateTo).ToList();
 foreach (var u in sp)
 {

        result += "<tr>";
        result += "<td>"+u.depno+"</td>";
        result += "</tr>";
        result += "</table>";
 }
 return result;
}
```

I used to return a table  and  to append it to the table in .aspx page but i stop,  because I want to show 3 tables in the page every table data will present an execution of procedure so, I don't know how to handle this, instead of tables i use 3 repeaters.
so i want to a way to change the **DataSource** of the repeater immediately whenever the user press a button.

***Note***: *If any one have an idea to present three tables instead of using 
repeaters, please provide it here.*